# I need to assign to "value" only the result when the condition of the map is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

I need to assign to "value" only the result when the condition of the map is true

```
const arr= [1,2,3,4,5];

value=arr.map(item => item>4  &&  item)
console.log(value);
```

result value=[false,false,false,false,5]
what i need: value=5;

Comment: Use filter instead

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the scenario using the .filter method instead.

```js
const arr= [1,2,3,4,5];

value=arr.filter(item => item>4  &&  item)

console.log(value);
```

Comment: value=parseFloat(arr.filter(item => item>4  &&  item )) Thanks

Comment: How about if there are more number of elements that match the condition?

Comment: const arr1= [1,2.1,3,8,4.2]; 
const arr2= [1,2.1,3,4,5]; 

arr1.map(item1 => 
{
const value=Math.max(...arr2.map(item2 => (item1 === item2  ? item2 : 0  )))
console.log(value)
}) //when the id from the first array matches an id from the second array -> show the id else show zero (this is what i needed)

Comment: ok , I understand , I think you missed to mention the same in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter!

```js
const arr= [1,2,3,4,5];

value=arr.filter(item => item>4  &&  item)
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a .filter(e=>e) at the end
(Short answer I’m on the phone )

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Array.prototype.filter()
```

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

**Syntax**

let newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index, [array]])[, thisArg])

[Read more in MDDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const arr= [1,2,3,4,5];

var value = arr.filter((number) => number > 4);

console.log(value)
```